# How to limit AWS resource consumption?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is any public file in s3 a open vault to someones wallet?

I have seen some scripts and external tools to monitor and react, i would like to know if currently there is any better way to limit AWS resource consumption.

Answer (score 3):

You can use CloudWatch (AWS internal monitor tool) to set up a [notification](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html) if some limit is reached. Once you get such a notification, you can limit the access to this bucket/file.

You can easily set up server access log (check [docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html)), that will allow you to check if you are being attacked, and by who. For example:

```
$ ./s3curl.pl --id YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --key YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -- -s -v 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket?logging' > mybucket.logging
```

You have a set of [restrictions](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/AccessPolicyLanguage_ElementDescriptions.html#Condition) that you can define. You can restrict based on IP range or even by referral (allow download the image, only if the referred site is your site). For example:

```
{
  "Version":"2008-10-17",
  "Id":"http referrer policy example",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests referred by www.mysite.com and mysite.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{
          "aws:Referer":[
            " http://www.mysite.com/*",
            " http://mysite.com/*"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Anyway, the price of a single hacker attack is rather low. S3 pricing are 0.12$ per GB and 0.01$ per 10,000 GET requests. It will take a huge effort and millions of requests to get you to a significant bill.

I recommend you to set up the notification above and track the access to your bucket before you go into effort to protect it.

Once you discover a problem you have the options above to protect it, as well as setting up a [VPC](http://aws.amazon.com/vpc/) (for no additional costs) and further control your content with your favourite security software.

Usually the problem is to get people to view your content, and S3 makes it easy to put up as much content as you want with rather low costs and effort.

Comment: s3 and AWS are really great, just trying to find the curent "canonical answer" to this issue. Thanks a lot for your contribution and pointers, will look into them.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does have some built-in limits (for instance, around 20 concurrent instances except if you fill [this form](http://aws.amazon.com/contact-us/ec2-request/))

The best bet, though, is to place some alarms and consolidade with tools like [newvem](http://www.newvem.com/)

Comment: Nice, thanks Aldrin. I wonder how big sites like coursera handles this. Shouldn't they worry that my public image on S3 can be suddenly DDoS'ed and get budget messed by a script kid?

Comment: It actually happened (http://www.behind-the-enemy-lines.com/2012/04/google-attack-how-i-self-attacked.html)

In some cases, AWS itself will call you when they notice a spike in your usage.

Answer (score -1):

Newvem is not availabe as it has been acquired by Datapipe now.

https://techcrunch.com/2013/09/10/datapipe-acquires-newvem-an-analytics-service-for-monitoring-aws/